# Access MAC keys in NaCl/libsodium

Tags: libsodium, nacl-cryptography

According to https://cr.yp.to/highspeed/naclcrypto-20090310.pdf, NaCl derives a MAC key from the shared secret and the nonce in `crypto_box` APIs.

> Alice uses the first 32 bytes of the long stream (generated from the shared secret and nonce using `salsa20`) to compute an authenticator of the encrypted packet.

However, this procedure is internal. I wonder if there is an API to derive the MAC key manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `box` construction uses the `xsalsa20` cipher (originally -- there is also a variant using `xchacha20`).

The first block of that cipher are used as a Poly1305 key. The remaining blocks are XORed with the message to compute the ciphertext.

So, you can simply use `crypto_stream()` to compute the Poly1305 key.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. IMO accessing the MAC key can be a useful API.

Comment: Probably not :) Remember that this is a one-time key. It should be used only once. Authenticating different messages (or ciphertexts) with the same key can lead to key recovery.